# How do I get an average of the last three grades for each kindergarden in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have two tables in SQL. The first one has the names of the kindergardens and their ID's. 
The second table consists of grade ID's, kindergarden's ID's, their grades and the date when they were graded.
I need to get an average of the last three grades for each kindergarden only.

These are the tables I have:

kindergarden
|kindergarden_id|kindergarden_name|kindergarden_address|kindergarden_user_id|

kindergarden_grade
|grade_id|grade|grade_date|kindergarden_kindergarden_id|

I'm currently trying this and with this query I get the average of all the grades I have, not the last three.

```
SELECT r.kindergarden_name, AVG(r.grade)FROM (SELECT kindergarden.kindergarden_name, kindergarden_grade.grade from kindergarden left join kindergarden_grade on kindergarden.kindergarden_id=kindergarden_grade.kindergarden_kindergarden_id order by kindergarden_grade.grade_date)as r group by r.kindergarden_name
```

This is what I get and that's the kindergardens and the average of all of their grades:

Corgi  3.0000
Butterfly 4.0000
Imagination 2.0000

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to get the last three grades:

```
SELECT k.kindergarden_name, AVG(r.grade)
FROM (SELECT k.kindergarden_name, kg.grade,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY k.kindergarden_name ORDER BY kg.grade_date) as seqnum
      FROM kindergarden k LEFT JOIN
           kindergarden_grade kg
           ON k.kindergarden_id = kg.kindergarden_kindergarden_id 
    ) k
WHERE seqnum <= 3
GROUP BY k.kindergarden_name;
```

EDIT:

Older version of MySQL do not support `ROW_NUMBER()`.  There are various solutions, but one is:

```
SELECT k.kindergarden_name, AVG(r.grade)
FROM kindergarden k LEFT JOIN
     kindergarden_grade kg
     ON k.kindergarden_id = kg.kindergarden_kindergarden_id 
WHERE kg.grade_date >= ANY (SELECT kg2.grade_date
                            FROM kindergarden_grade kg2
                            WHERE kg2.kindergarden_kindergarden_id = kg.kindergarden_kindergarden_id
                            ORDER BY kg2.grade_date DESC
                            LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
                           )
 GROUP BY k.kindergarden_name;
```

This uses a subquery to return the third newest date.  The `ANY` handles the situation where there are not three dates for a particular kindergarden.

Comment: a suugestion. It'll be immensely helpful if there are helpful resources added in your answers. Such resources will aid both the OP and the readers in understanding the underlying semantics of the code snippets. I'm suggesting this because I see you've deep knowledge on this subject given the great books you've written. Please think about it.

Comment: I'm using myPHPadmin for the database and I'm getting the 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax" for the line where there's windows functions: "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY k.kindergarden_name ORDER BY kg.grade_date) as seqnum". Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @AntonioOletić . . . What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: We're obliged to use an online myPHPdatabase 4.5.4.1 that the college provides. I'm having a hard time finding the exact MySQL version that this database is on.